# How to detect Active Directory path in c#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I've been searching through the internet to learn how to interact with Active Directory. I find the following piece of code but I want to know what `ActiveDirectoryPath` must be ?

Any brief description of the code is welcome

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(ActiveDirectoryPath);
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

search.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectCategory=group)(cn={0}))", activeDirectoryGroup);
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
SearchResult searchResult = search.FindOne();

if (searchResult == null)
    return new HashSet<User>();

DirectoryEntry group = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
Hashtable searchedGroups = new Hashtable();
return GetUsersInGroup(group.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value.ToString(), searchedGroups, path);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely clear what you mean by *detect Active Directory path* - there's really no "current" AD path or anything; there's no "current directory" like in your file system.

You can determine the system default path by inspecting the `LDAP://RootDSE` entry and looking for the `defaultNamingContext` there:

```
using (DirectoryEntry deRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE"))
{
    if (deRoot.Properties["defaultNamingContext"] != null)
    {
        string defaultNamingContext = 
               deRoot.Properties["defaultNamingContext"].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Or you can just retrieve the currently logged in user from Active Directory, and inspect it's LDAP path (this code works on .NET 3.5 and newer with the new `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace):

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
     UserPrincipal currentUser = UserPrincipal.Current;
     string userLdapPath = currentUser.DistinguishedName;
}
```

This will return the full LDAP path for the user, which contains the "container" that user is created in - something like:

```
LDAP://CN=User Name,OU=SomeOU,DC=YourCompany,DC=Com
```

and here the `OU=SomeOU,DC=YourCompany,DC=Com` part is the "path" in the Active Directory where this user exists inside of.

Comment: does this code valid for terminal access to the server?If yes how can I do that?